# Incline Paradox?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

Suppose I have an inclined plane as shown
If I have a body kept on the incline and released . If I break it's weight into two components , I can break it into one perpendicular to plane and the other at an angle with the incline in direction of groove A or B Or C (in picture).while solving problems we break down components in A direction. why not directly in B and mgsinx.
If so all of them will reach in equal time.
But that is not the case
And also if something is thrown (with some velocity) at such an angle to the inline it tends to come in the direction of incline.Which force is responsible for the prodigal's return(I mean the ball's)
So what am I missing here?

[image: the incline]

Comment: "*If so all of them will reach in equal time*" :O I wasn't even aware that anything was moving in this description. Would you mind clarifying - also, the sketch is really not clear. Would you mind clarifying that as well?

Comment: Oh sorry was thinking faster than I was typing.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what you are asking here, there definitely needs to be a lot of clarification and editing done here. The drawing is not clear so either another better picture or diagram should be provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't quite understand what you're asking, but a note on force resolution might be useful…

You can resolve a force into components in 3 perpendicular directions simply by multiplying the magnitude of the force by the cosine of the angle between the force and each chosen direction in turn.

If you choose one of your directions to be normal to the plane, then you can choose any two directions *in the plane* and perpendicular to each other for your other two directions.

If one of these directions is the line of greatest slope, then the 'third' direction is a horizontal one, and the weight will have no component in this direction.

But if you choose your 'C' direction, you must realise that there will be a third non-zero component of weight, in a direction lying in the plane and at right angles to the C direction.

Comment: And with C the sum of your components in the plane will end up being the same as if you just picked the line of greatest slope, right?

Comment: Yes indeed! [Vector sum, of course.]

Comment: Always vector sum

Comment: Yes, but I thought I better emphasise it in case anyone in the early stages of learning Physics happens to read these comments.

Comment: Oh yeah I knew I messed up my 3D . Thanks. You answered what I asked without understanding my question totally. Thanks.